# Orientación sobre eventos

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy probando a crear una app en Android Studio y estoy usando una BBDD de FireStore que sumistra datos a la app.

Mi pregunta es:

Si por ejemplo, el dia 10/10/2019 a las 12:00 hay grabada en la base de datos un evento (supongamos un partido en los que los usuarios han echo un pronóstico) ¿Como hago para que se desarrolle ese evento aun cuando  no haya nadie conectado? ¿Se puede hacer con Firebase o habría que hacerlo con MySQL?

Estoy totalmente perdido en este sentido y no se por donde empezar. Con que me orientéis con algo me llega, muchas gracias.

Comment: Buscas una tarea programada? es decir, que a determinada hora se ejecute una determinada tarea

Comment: Supongo que sera eso. Tengo creado un calendario con los eventos y me gustaría que se celebrasen en su momento. Por ejempl en un madrid - barcelona los usuarios pronostican un resultado antes del partido. Se ejecuta el evento y se puntua a los que han pronosticado.

Comment: Por lo que he encontrado en [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428016/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-firebird-stored-procedure-at-specific-time) pregunta parece ser que desde firebird no existe ninguna manera especifica, tal vez donde tengas alojado el servidor puedas hacerlo. Desde MySQL puedes probar [esto](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/)

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, sobre todo esto: *¿Como hago para que se desarrolle ese evento aun cuando no haya nadie conectado?* Si explicas más claramente lo que quieres quizá podamos ayudarte mejor. @NicolasOñate, Firebird y Firebase no es lo mismo. Si se trata de actualizaciones en tiempo real, Firebase es excelente para eso. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano vaya! no me había dado cuenta! pues supongo que mejor para todos

Comment: @NicolasOñate la sincronización de Firebase en tiempo real es impresionante. Cambias algún contenido y se refleja de inmediato en tu App.

Comment: @A.Cedano Pues supongo que es lo que busca el OP, ya que quiere que en el momento que finalice el partido se refleje el resultado

Comment: @NicolasOñate no sé, el planteamiento es confuso.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91704/discussion-between-nicolas-onate-and-a-cedano).